# Mongo Tree Data Model Design

Tags: mongodb, tree, schema

My goal is to design a scalable recursive tree data model that is agnostic to vertical size, horizontal size, tree imbalances, and overall size.

On Mongo's site, they talk about tree structured data here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/

Interestingly, each data model they present indicate a new entry into a collection; even for the sub-elements

Let's call the following from mongodb.org example A:

```
db.categories.insert( { _id: "MongoDB", parent: "Databases" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "dbm", parent: "Databases" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Databases", parent: "Programming" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Languages", parent: "Programming" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Programming", parent: "Books" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Books", parent: null } )
```

Now, let's call this one example B:

```
singleEntry =
{
    _id: "Books",
    children:
    [
        {
            _id: "Programming",
            parent: "Books",
            children:
            [
                {
                    _id: "Languages",
                    parent: "Programming"
                },
                {
                    _id: "Databases",
                    parent: "Programming",
                    children:
                    [
                        {
                            _id: "MongoDB",
                            parent: "Databases"
                        },
                        {
                            _id: "dbm",
                            parent: "Databases"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

db.categories.insert(singleEntry)
```

I really like example B; though having the parent-child relation double referenced is uncomfortably redundant, I could not find a way to avoid this in practical usage.  Also, the queries are a bit more involved:

```
db.categories.find(
    {
        'children.children.children._id' : 'MongoDB'
    }
)
```

but I don't mind as long as everything in example A is possible with example B.

I get the feeling it might not be. Other gotcha's I'm worried about are:

1. maximum entry size
2. maximum stack size
3. inserting into a highly nested collection entry creating havoc on the engine that rearranges stuff in memory

My initial understanding of Mongodb was that it's intended for schema design like this. However when I look at the documentation, examples, even the shell methods, it looks like they really intended it to be like example A.

Something about example A seems too relation-y; it's kind of what I was trying to get away from. If I go with example A, why not just use SQL? If I go with example B, what can I expect to run into?

Answer (score 3):

One problem you will run into is the [document size limit of 16MB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size). That is an absolute killer for the approach in Sample B, except for very small databases.

NoSQL – and MongoDB – data modelling works fundamentally different than data modelling for SQL databases. The following is a bit simplified, but you get the picture.

With SQL databases, you model your data according to your entities and identify their relations to each other. In a next step, you try to identify how you can answer the questions emerging from your use cases.

In MongoDB data modelling, you first identify the questions emerging from your use cases and then you model your data accordingly to answer your questions in the most efficient way.

Furthermore, there *are* use cases in which NoSQL databases in general or MongoDB specifically aren't ideal. However, modelling tree structures in SQL databases usually is a pain in the neck, too. Using a tree database like Neo4J might be more suitable for *heavily* structured trees. However, a category structure for a shop system or sth can be built with almost any database. I'd choose the database based on almost any other functional and non-functional requirements of the project.